# Spring 3 + MyBatis 3

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, spring, mybatis

How to create multiple connection databases in spring 3 and mybatis 3. I need to connect to MySQL and Oracle at once.
Can you help me?

Comment: I know you can specify the environment in your SqlMapConfig file, so you could setup the multiple evironments there, and setup separate DAOs for each

Answer (score 1):

You need 1 SqlSessionFactory per database.

```
<bean id="db1SqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:sqlmap1.xml"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="db1datasource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="db2SqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:sqlmap2.xml"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="db2datasource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="db1SqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <qualifier value="db1" />
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="db1SqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>


<bean id="db2SqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <qualifier value="db2" />
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="db2SqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```